# How can i minimize my code to one api ? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having two api's which are doing same work.
1) By default, I'm getting the current date employee data.
2) I'm passing the parameters to get the selected date data.
How can I minimize my code to one api?

```
 app.controller("attCtrl", ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
jQuery("body").on("focus", ".time-input", function () {
if (!jQuery(this).data('xdsoft_datetimepicker')) {
    jQuery(this).datetimepicker({
        onGenerate: function () {
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('initial')) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('initial').triggerHandler('open.xdsoft');
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
$scope.empattendance = [],
//I want to send default date while calling this api
$http.get('xyz/api/att/view/date')
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $scope.empattendance = result.data.result;
    $scope.empDetails = result.data.result1;
}, function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});

 $scope.getEmpAttendance = function () {
var employeeAttendance = {
    startdate: jQuery('#start').val(),
    enddate: jQuery('#end').val(),
    employee: $scope.selectedItem
}
employeeAttendance.startdate = employeeAttendance.startdate.slice(0, -6);
employeeAttendance.enddate = employeeAttendance.enddate.slice(0, -6);
console.log(employeeAttendance);
$http.get('xyz/api/att/view/today', employeeAttendance)
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $scope.empattendance = result.data.result;
    });
   }
}]);
```

Comment: You can write this API call and response in a service and use in your controller. Also, you can pass `date` as parameter so that you can use single get function

Answer (score 0):

You can write service for API call or go for single function in controller as follows :

```
app.controller("attCtrl", ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $filter, $http) {

     $scope.empattendance = [];
     function getDetails(urlDate,employeeAttendance){
        employeeAttendance = employeeAttendance || '';
        return $http.get('xyz/api/att/view/'+urlDate, employeeAttendance);
     }
     //call API with default date
     getDetails('date')
       .then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
          $scope.empattendance = result.data.result;
          $scope.empDetails = result.data.result1;
       }, function(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
      });

    $scope.getEmpAttendance = function() {
       var employeeAttendance = {
         startdate: jQuery('#start').val(),
         enddate: jQuery('#end').val(),
         employee: $scope.selectedItem
    }
    employeeAttendance.startdate = employeeAttendance.startdate.slice(0, -6);
    employeeAttendance.enddate = employeeAttendance.enddate.slice(0, -6);
    // call API with date
    getDetails('today',employeeAttendance)
     .then(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
       $scope.empattendance = result.data.result;
    });
  }
}]);
```

Hope this helps!